# connection to excel file in c # wpf

Tags: c#, oledb, oledbconnection

I'm trying to connect to an excel file as a bank using
  OleDbConnection, until then I can connect but however I try to make a select, it does not inform me an error:

> The microsoft office access database engine did not find the 'folhadb'
>   object. Make sure the object exists and you spell its name and the
>   path name correctly

Which is very strange because in my excel file I defined the first sheet with the name of 'folhadb'

```
 public async Task<ObservableCollection<Employee>> GetDataFormExcelAsync()
 {
     ObservableCollection<Employee> Employees = new ObservableCollection<Employee>();
     await Conn.OpenAsync();
     Cmd = new OleDbCommand();
     Cmd.Connection = Conn;
     Cmd.CommandText = "Select * from [folhadb]";
     var Reader = await Cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
     while (Reader.Read())
     {
         Employees.Add(new Employee()
         {
             Id= Convert.ToInt32(Reader["Id"]),
             Name = Reader["Name"].ToString(),
             Date = Reader["Date"].ToString(),

         });
     }
     Reader.Close();
     Conn.Close();
     return Employees;
 }
```

Comment: what is the path that the engine is searching in - and where have you kept the file?

Comment: path= C:\Users\bruhh\Desktop\Dados.xlsx
 Conn = new OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source="+path+";Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES;\"");

Comment: where are you specifying the folhadb object?

Comment: how so specifying? Folhadb is not just the name of an excel spreadsheet?

Comment: you're asking for folhadb somewhere in your code and the engine cannot find it. where are you asking for the folhadb sheet? paste in the full code otherwise it's hard to see

Comment: okay, i add code

Comment: what happens if you try get get the schema? `DataTable dbSchema = Conn.GetOleDbSchemaTable (OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null);`

Comment: maybe it could be that the connection isn''t built properly: why not try building the connection string using the OleDbConnectionStringBuilder class? then you will more easily be able to spot issues. apart from that I have no idea. good luck though

Comment: The structure is perfectly created, I do not know what it can be either. thank you so much.